# How to get oauth credentials of logged-in firebase authenticated user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have created a firebase authentication using google OAuth. When I am signing in for the first time, we have a function that spills the google OAuth's access-token - I am using this token to call a googleapis. But I am looking for the same access-token when I am coming back to my web-app. I have the currentUser, but I am unable to figure out as on how to get the creds.

```
 const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(async (result) => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        console.log("token", token)
        // IdP data available using getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
        // ...
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error)
      });
  }
```

In this code `token` is giving me the output I want. I want the same thing once I come back or refresh my web-app.
Something that I can fetch with `auth.currentUser` or something like that.

I tried this code.

```
auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idTokenResult);
        // const token = credential.accessToken;
      console.log("idTokenResult", idTokenResult, "-----------------token", credential)
      // Confirm the user is an Admin.
    })
```

Result

```
{
    "idToken": {
        "claims": {
            "name": "Shenor shai",
            "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNmyxMdzHBqcvUriJvQPyYc2PhdjrIA=s96-c",
            "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/chainlink-hackathon-23",
            "aud": "random",
            "auth_time": 1684419631,
            "user_id": "aofhafihfiafhafia",
            "sub": "aofhafihfiafhafia",
            "iat": 1684421034,
            "exp": 1684424634,
            "email": "random@gmail.com",
            "email_verified": true,
            "firebase": {
                "identities": {
                    "google.com": [
                        "118112290937553408948"
                    ],
                    "email": [
                        "random@gmail.com"
                    ]
                },
                "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
            }
        },
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFiYjI2MzY4YTNkMWExNDg1YmNhNTJiNGY4M2JkYjQ5YjY0ZWM2MmYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ..U5Gmr-vt_paxbUck2UNGlKifrVk2FhygoBGoxatTBcQ_j6wZi9FZs6s6-pajQLq5nrVIMOM_8W9yJN_gCg0V8W0gl2cmAH8uREZDg5G2lWOunTD8Nbze0yrg6us5_hctThZ8uxrXFD_kPvVLJO6tJZeoI8A2eW-kzg7xcP4B8_Y9qc6QpJguJf4PqxE7522bQ7fI3tu_T0vNAk0Bt36o-K-Adr1guL4Mxj3PNs0WKEPen9iiirAoPjOFtVY_Pk46-paXwVtBLP8tC3H1ZN0ysp9DwD99JsejvGUWthlX9Qz_0GqnrDXBrst3O5OFwQKYzbbtv_vs_A8PdJc6A9Uk-A",
        "authTime": "Thu, 18 May 2023 14:20:31 GMT",
        "issuedAtTime": "Thu, 18 May 2023 14:43:54 GMT",
        "expirationTime": "Thu, 18 May 2023 15:43:54 GMT",
        "signInProvider": "google.com",
        "signInSecondFactor": null
    },
    "pendingToken": null,
    "providerId": "google.com",
    "signInMethod": "google.com"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this?